# Losing the .txt extension of .txt.gz file after saving a python requests response as .gz

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, gzip, python-requests-html

I have a list of HTTP URLs which return file content and I have saved those in a file. I don't know which URL will return what file content type. One of the URLs, when manually loaded on browser, downloads a .txt.gz file. However when I check for the content type of the request response it is `application/x-gzip`, and the file signature is `1f8b08` indicating a .gz file. When I save this file as .gz, the .txt extension of internal file is lost. And a file without any extension is present in the saved .gz file.

Is there any way to know what the file type of the file compressed inside the .gz or .zip file is from the requests content? Or to know that the file is a .txt.gz file?

[image]

In the image above we can see that the file inside 12345.gz does not have a .txt extension when I write the response content to a .gz file. But when I load the URL manually, the internal file has a .txt extension.

After reading the response content:

[image]

I am able to identify that the file signature is for .gz file but is there any way to know that file inside .gz archive is .txt or other type of file.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zawnu_sX_zYal67TJjBowsJH2eJ4V27M?usp=sharing) is an example of .gz file i get by manually downloading and saving the response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And provide one example of gzip content, either as a link, or as the actual content encoding in base64 in the question, if it's not too big.

Comment: What does "a file without any extension is present in the saved .gz file" mean exactly?

Comment: @MarkAdler the file does not have any extension to it. since on loading the url manually it download a file with extension .txt.gz the file inside gzip is a .txt file. Since i am unable to know the file type as .txt.gz the file is getting stored as .gz so the internal file does not have .txt extension.

Comment: Your hex dump image is neither of the files you linked (`what_i_get.gz` and `what_i_want.gz`). The hex dump has no file name in the gzip header, whereas `what_i_get.gz` has the name `12345` in the header, and `what_i_want.gz` has `12345.txt` in the header. Also the contents are slightly different, where `what_i_want` has a carriage return before the line feed, whereas `what_i_get` just has the line feed.

Comment: Note that the name in the header is only used for decompression by the `gunzip` command if the `-N` option is used. So if you `gunzip what_i_get.gz`, the resulting file name will be `what_i_get`. If you `gunzip -N what_i_get.gz`, the resulting file name will be `12345`.

Comment: You wrote "One of the URLs, when manually loaded on browser...". What browser? Can you provide the URL?